# How do I prevent the warning about 'System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail' being obsolete?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, compiler-warnings

How to prevent this warning?

> Warning: 'System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail' is obsolete: 'The recommended alternative is System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'    ~\SendMail.cs MailTest

Comment: Do what it says. And this has nothing to do with winforms.

Answer (score 6):

You can selectively disable certain compiler warnings by using [`#pragma warning disable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx), and then re-enable those warnings with `#pragma warning restore`.

The warning codes related to the use of functions marked with the `[Obsolete]` attribute are [CS0612](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0h063ka.aspx) and [CS0618](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e.aspx).

So you could wrap the call(s) to the obsolete function(s) as follows:

```
#pragma warning disable 0612, 0618
    // Your code that calls obsolete functions
    // ...
#pragma warning restore 0612, 0618
```

The `restore` at the end is important, because it ensures that warnings about using obsolete functions get turned back on again. It's good practice only to ignore specific warnings for a good, well-documented reason! Comment the `#pragma` statements liberally.

The best alternative, of course, is to do what it says and switch to using the recommended alternative: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`. Make this a goal for your next version or refactoring effort.